# Why data layer is used while we can write most of the code in stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, stored-procedures, three-tier

Why is a data layer used while we can write most of the code in stored procedures itself? What are the advantages and disadvantages in it?
`Data layer` is an important layer in `3 tier architecture`, which handles all the database related tasks. My question is that, whether we can achieve this using a stored procedure itself in most of the cases? In that case, what is the major advantage in using that layer?

EDIT:

The question was just to get clear idea about the usage of data layer and database stored procedures. I have got an answer below which helped me in that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3-tier approach is for when you wish to maybe use different Database Engine types.

From [Multitier architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture)

> **Data tier**
>
> This tier consists of database servers. Here information is stored and
>   retrieved. This tier keeps data neutral and independent from
>   application servers or business logic. Giving data on its own tier
>   also improves scalability and performance.

Answer (score 2):

In stored procedure goes your query logic, in data access layer you connect with database engine

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973829.aspx),
[N-Tier-Architecture-and-Tips](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/430014/N-Tier-Architecture-and-Tips) have good insight on n-tier architecture

Answer (score 0):

You can't unit test stored procs very easily because you can't easily mock the data in the database